# Two Laravel sites with same code, but POST routes in one return a 404 error

Tags: laravel, configuration, routes, http-status-code-404

I am facing a very weird problem, the code base for both my site is the same. I decided to have another web server to help with load balancing, but on this second site, I cannot log in. All my routes are present, but my POST routes return a `404 error (Not Found)`, it's weird because everything works fine on my original site. I don't seem to understand why this could happen. Also, why only GET methods return the page and POST requests get a 404 Error? Someone, please help.

Answer (score 0):

It was nginx that was filtering post request. Just putting it here it can help someone!